# Looping through a handle to get inner elements texts

Tags: puppeteer

I have retrieved all elements of the class (".col.double.societe.u2d.hasLogo" ), i would like to loop each of them to retrieve the class ('.adresse') texts

My code is:

```
const societeHandles = await page.$$('.col.double.societe.u2d.hasLogo');
for(const societeHandle of societeHandles){
     const adresse = await societeHandle.$eval(".adresse");
```

But i got run error Error: failed to find element matching selector ".adresse"

the classe is there:

```
<p class="adresse">
   325 rue Pasteur
   <br><a href="/annuaire/aquitaine/gironde/bordeaux">33200 Bordeaux</a>
   <br><a href="/annuaire/aquitaine/gironde">Gironde</a>
   <br><a href="/annuaire/aquitaine">Aquitaine</a>
 </p>
```

Am i allow to do it ? or is it a syntax error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puppeteer can't locate the address element because of the selector you chose to locate all of them, it's probably too specific. Try `.col.double.societe`.

```
require('puppeteer').launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('http://www.dollmedia-btp.com/annuaire/aquitaine/gironde/bordeaux');

    const societeHandles = await page.$$('.col.double.societe');

    // Have we got any addresses?
    console.log("Total count: " + societeHandles.length)

    for(const societeHandle of societeHandles){
        const adresse = await societeHandle.$eval(".adresse", el => el.textContent.trim());
        console.log(adresse + "\n")
    }

  await browser.close();
});
```

It is also a handy practice to log if anything found during the request at all, so I logged the number of found nodes.

Also note the correct use of [`handle.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1): you pass the function a `selector` and also a `function` to execute in the browser context. (In my example I just return the text from found elements)